# Need 600dpi JPEG file smaller than 5MB

Tags: image-compression, jpeg

In order to submit a document to an online website, they require the following:

- Scan the US letter-size hard-copy document at 600 dpi in greyscale
- Provide a JPEG, JPG, or PNG file of the scan with a maximum size of 5 MB

When I scan at 600dpi and create a JPG with no compression, I get an 8.5 MB file.  So, I used (FastStone image) software to compress it down below 5 MB.  When I submitted that document, the website automatically responded "document unacceptable - less than 600 dpi."

Is it possible to create what they are requesting?  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If your document has at least 5100×6600 pixels, then that's its resolution, no matter the compresson. Their website is broken in that case and it's not up to you to fix that. Nor is it up to us, to be honest.

Comment: Look if the following helps: open the JPEG file using IrfanView (a free lightweight image viewing program) and press  *I* which shows an *image information* window, there you will see the line *resolution*, and check if it's set as 600 x 600 in the edit box; if that box is empty or shows another value, then write there 600 and click *change* and click *ok*. Then **save** the file again as JPEG; This will indicate into the file that the file is scanned at 600 dpi even if it was not.

Comment: OK - thanks for the replies.  I had suspected the (government) website was faulty (although I would think they would have problems from all submitters and would fix it).  The document properties of the compressed jpeg do indeed remain 600x600 dpi.  Now I just have to fight city hall - what could be easier.